# JavaScript Library to add text and images to a “canvas” and aligning them

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What I am trying to achieve, is the following JS funtionality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Wqv.jpg. There are essentially three tabs. I should be able to add some text to the canvas (the font is customizable), I cannot move the text, only align it as it shown on screenshots, the same logic is for images. The question is, is there a VueJs (preferably) or other JS library to achieve this or at least alike funtionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [Fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/) help you?

I believe that you would need to create event handlers for the "align" buttons to reposition the object (text or image) you want to manipulate.

Comment: Thanks, the framework contains all the stuff I need!